# Filling Algorithm for Equal Distribution

Tags: python, algorithm, dart

Need your help resolving algorithm task -
There are 3 baskets, basket 1 has 10 balls and a possible max capacity of 100, basket 2 has 50 balls and a possible max capacity of 200, and basket 3 has 100 balls and a possible max capacity of 300.
Please help me to write an algorithm or code that split another 100 balls between the 3 baskets for the best possible equal distribution between the baskets.
Not possible to move balls between the baskets.

Your suggested algorithm should of course work on any number of baskets with different max capacities and any onHand value, for example, 1 ball that I want to add or the maximum capacity value that should fill all baskets to 100% fill.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your problem more? What do you mean with "_best possible equal distribution_"

Comment: As each basket has different capacity and fill, 
then not always possible to bring all baskets to the exact same %fill rate without moving balls between baskets.
for example, one basket has 9 of max capacity of 10 balls,  and another basket has 1 ball of 100 max capacity.
and i want to add 1 ball, it's not possible to add this ball to one of the baskets and make the exact same %fill rate, so it's should count the best possible distribution.

Comment: [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166)

Comment: It's not homework. the question is whether there is such an algorithm that can do this.

Comment: From what I understood, you could try to give the balls to the basket with the lowest percentage respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned in one of my comments. If you want to have an equal distribution of %fill, then you could add the balls individually to the current lowest filled basket:

```py
import numpy as np

def fill_baskets(baskets, ballsToDistribute):
    for i in range(ballsToDistribute, 0, -1):
        # find the basket with the lowest percentage of balls in it
        currFillLevels = [currFill / maxFill for currFill, maxFill in baskets]
        minIndex = np.argmin(currFillLevels)

        # give the ball to this basket
        baskets[minIndex][0] += 1

    return baskets


baskets = [[10, 100], [50, 200], [100, 300]]

new_baskets = fill_baskets(baskets, 100)

# print the result:
for i, basket in enumerate(new_baskets):
    print(f"Basket {i+1}: {basket[0]/basket[1]:.3f}% ({basket[0]}/ {basket[1]})")
```

The output I get for this case if the following:

```
Basket 1: 0.440% (44/ 100)
Basket 2: 0.435% (87/ 200)
Basket 3: 0.430% (129/ 300)
```

The only problem that can arise from the code is when we have too many balls to give away. Then all the baskets will be overfilled.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Thank you.
Do you think it is possible to do it better than O(n) complexity?

Comment: @MichaelVish If this is the answer you were looking for, you could like it, so others with a similar problem know that it works.  If I find some free time, I can try to optimize it.